# How to stream repeated fields into bigquery for non-records?

Tags: google-api, google-bigquery

I'm streaming data into Google bigquery. I have a repeated field, but I'm receiving the following error:

```
[{"errors"=[
    {"debugInfo"="generic::invalid_argument: This field is not a record.", 
     "location"="hashtags", 
     "message"="This field is not a record.", 
     "reason"="invalid"}], 
  "index"=0}]
```

The schema contains:

```
...,
{
  "name": "hashTags",
  "type": "string",
  "mode": "repeated"
}
```

I'm passing a list of strings for `hashTags` in the JSON I'm sending.

What's going wrong and how can I fix it? I don't really want to have to make a single-field value into a record.

Comment: Can you share how you're formatting your JSON?  If you're trying to stream a repeated string, the JSON for that field should look like: `{..., "hashTags": ["#foo", "#bar", "#baz"], ...}`

Comment: @DannyKitt I'm pretty sure that's how it's submitting it. I'm using the Java SDK and setting a list as the data, so I assume it's submitting it as a list like you've described.

Comment: @jbrown Could you please send us the code snippet and sample row content so we can reproduce and investigate it? Feel free to send to chengz@google.com if you don't want to post it publicly. Thanks!

Comment: Any update on that? I'm experiencing the same issue but with a `REQUIRED` field.

Comment: I had a similar problem and the issue was that I was sending a timestamp as a java.util.Date. Using long fixed it.